# Powershell looping through message queues

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to return tables with message queues from three different environments. I could copy and paste the existing code for all three, but I want to make it cleaner and more reusable.

Is there a way to loop through each message queue and return them in separate tables (i.e.: Dev, Dev2, Dev3 queues)?

```
[object]$dev3Queues = gwmi -class Win32_PerfFormattedData_msmq_MSMQQueue -computerName      myServer | Where{$_.Name -like "*dev3*" }  | select Name,MessagesInQueue #| Out-File "C:\test.txt"
[object]$dev2Queues = gwmi -class Win32_PerfFormattedData_msmq_MSMQQueue -computerName myServer | Where{$_.Name -like "*dev2*" }  | select Name,MessagesInQueue #| Out-File "C:\test2.txt"


[object]$devQueues = gwmi -class Win32_PerfFormattedData_msmq_MSMQQueue -computerName myServer | 
Where{$_.Name -notlike "*dev2*" -AND $_.Name -notlike "*dev3*" -AND $_.Name -notlike "*private*" -AND $_.Name -notlike "*Computer Queues*" -AND $_.Name -notlike "*uat*"} | select Name,MessagesInQueue #| Out-File "C:\test3.txt"

$Html = "<html><head>Whoo Queues</head><body><table border=1>"
foreach($element in $devQueues)
{
$Html += "<tr><td>" + $element.Name + "</td><td>"+ $element.MessagesInQueue + "</td>    </tr>"
}


 $Html += "</table></body></html>"

 $Html | out-file C:\temp\DEVQueues.html

 #environmentloop - dev,dev2,dev3
 #{

 #queue loop + html 

 #}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`ConvertTo-Html`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849944.aspx) cmdlet with the option `-Fragment` to convert a list of objects to an HTML table of the object properties.

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_PerfFormattedData_msmq_MSMQQueue |
  select Name, MessagesInQueue |
  ConvertTo-Html -Fragment
```

Also, when running `Get-WmiObject` against a remote server using a WMI filter provides better performance than retrieving all results and filtering them on the local host with `Where-Object`.

```
$computer = 'myServer'
$filter   = 'Name LIKE "%dev3%"'

Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_PerfFormattedData_msmq_MSMQQueue -Computer $computer `
  -Filter $filter
```

However, since you want to filter the same dataset for various criteria, in your case the best approach might be to first fetch all relevant data from the remote host with a more general WMI filter (to avoid multiple remote connections), and then process them locally with several `Where-Object` filters:

```
$server    = 'myServer'
$wmiFilter = 'NOT (Name LIKE "%private%" OR Name LIKE "%Computer Queues%" ' +
             'OR Name LIKE "%uat%")'
$psFilters = { $_.Name -like "*dev3*" },
             { $_.Name -like "*dev2*" },
             { $_.Name -notlike "*dev2*" -and $_.Name -notlike "*dev3*" }

$data = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_PerfFormattedData_msmq_MSMQQueue `
          -Computer $server -Filter $wmiFilter

'<html><head>Whoo Queues</head><body>'
foreach ($filter in $psFilters) {
  $data | ? $filter | select Name, MessagesInQueue | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment
}
'</body></html>'
```

Comment: That worked really well to get the queues and format them. Is there any way to get the loop printing out specific names for each table (i.e.: "Dev1 Queues", "Dev2 Queues", etc) or is it a matter of adjusting the html?

Comment: @parabellum27 I don't think `ConvertTo-Html` provides this functionality, so you probably have to use string replacements on the generated HTML string: `($data | ... | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment) -replace '<table>',"<table id='something'>"`.